# Simple_form desabilitando item de seleção de acordo com situação do cadastro

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tenho um `f.association` que traz todos os clientes cadastrados. No cliente tenho um campo `status`.

Gostaria de que quando o status estiver `false`, o cliente apareça no select box, mas não seja selecionável, isto é possível?

Sei como usar o `disabled` no HTML, o que preciso saber é se é possível fazer isto com o `simple_form` no rails. Por exemplo: `f.association, algum_parametro => false`.

O meu código que gera este select está o mais simple possível:

`simple_form_for(@packing_list) do |f|
    f.association :client`

Comment: Adell, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você poderia editar a pergunta e postar o trecho da sua tela que gera o `select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [documentação](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) no GitHub contém um exemplo de integração do `simple_form` com um *helper* do Rails 3, o qual permite então passar um *hash* de atributos adicionais para cada opção.

Veja:

```
<%= f.input :role do %>
  <%= f.select :role, 
               Role.all.map { |r| [r.name, r.id, { class: r.company.id }] },
               include_blank: true %>
<% end %>
```

No exemplo, um atributo `class` é definido. Um `disabled` condicional poderia ser feito da seguinte forma;

```
<%= f.input :role do %>
  <%= f.select :role, 
               Role.all.map { |r| [r.name, r.id, { 
                   class: r.company.id, 
                   disabled: ('disabled' if r.status) }] 
               }.reject{ |k,v| v.nil? },
               include_blank: true %>
<% end %>
```

O trecho acima cria um *hash* contendo `disabled='disabled'` quanto `status` é verdadeiro ou `disabled=nil` quando `status` é falso. Depois, o `reject` remove os atributos nulos, necessário pois somente a presença do `disabled` desabilitaria o item. Essa ideia do *hash* foi baseada numa [questão do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750770/conditional-key-value-in-a-ruby-hash).

Sinceramente, a documentação é um tanto escassa, portanto não sei se é a forma mais adequada.